# Finding the right format for pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert strings in my dataset('2016-01-01 00:00:00') to time stamps using pd.to_datetime.
Im trying:

`pd.to_datetime(train["timestamp"],format='%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S')`

but I get

`time data '2016-01-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S' (match)`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to be in the specific format that you mentioned, that is `%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S`, then do it like this.

First convert your string to datetime format using `to_datetime`:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Now that your column is in datetime format, convert to the following format using `strftime`:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %I:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
             timestamp
0  2016/01/01 12:00:00
1  2016/01/01 12:00:00
```

As others pointed out, use `%H` instead of `%I` for 24 hour format, like this:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 2):

2 issues here:

1. Use `-` instead of `/`
2. `%I` is for `Hour 00-12`, use `%H` for `Hour 00-23`

```py
pd.to_datetime(train["timestamp"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I'm still geting the error: time data '2016-01-01 00:00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: You should use `%H` instead of `%I`, i have edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

That's because your format in your `df` is different. Try the following using `-`, also use `%H` for 24-hour clock:

```
pd.to_datetime(train["timestamp"],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```